# Voting (increase counter) of the predicted class to select the maximum voting one in python

Tags: python, classification, prediction, voting

I have dataset with 100 class and want to make a prediction. My structure contains 8 classifier, each classifier refer to some class label. I want to make vote to each output class label from each classifier (each resulted class makes to increase its counter) to select the maximum voting one as a final prediction because more than one classifier refer to it. My output of each classifier and its probability is as bellow:

```
class1: 49.77
class1: 34.95
class2: 98.37
class2: 99.92
class2: 99.93
class2: 99.24
class2: 56.20
class3: 57.15
```

I want to select class2 as a final prediction because it have the maximum vote (more than one classifier refer to it) how can I do that, can anyone please help me? any information may be helpful.